# Round top right and bottom right corners of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I need to round specific corner of my image view and uiview 
Imgview Top left and Top right 
View Bottom left and Bottom right.

and I explore and find this method

```
[self setMaskTo:_viewBookNow byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft];
[self setMaskTo:_viewBookNow byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomRight|UIRectCornerBottomRight];

[self setMaskTo:_imgVAnimal byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopRight];
[self setMaskTo:_imgVAnimal byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft];
```

Method definition is this

```
- (void)setMaskTo:(UIView*)view byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners
{
UIBezierPath *rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds
                                              byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                    cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0, 8.0)];
CAShapeLayer *shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];
view.layer.mask = shape;
}
```

but it only round left corners of view and image not work for right corners.

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: Use `clipsToBounds = true` & `maskstobounds = true` and try

Comment: Property masks to bounds not for view. showing this error.

Comment: Not working.....

Comment: Use `view.layer.masktobounds = true` Its a layer property.

Answer (score 0):

> Objective C Solution -

```
- (void)setMaskTo:(UIView*)view byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners
{
    UIBezierPath *rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds
                                                  byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                        cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
    CAShapeLayer *shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];
    view.layer.mask = shape;
}
```

And use it like this -

```
[self setMaskTo:viewToRound byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight];
```

> Swift Solution -

Please create this extension in your file first

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Then create a custom subclass of the UIView and write these lines in that class

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.roundCorners([.topLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 50)
}
```

Set those specific corners in the array as per your need.

Also set the clipToBounds = true in the storyboard or programatically.

Comment: Thanks Prateek I need objective C code and same I have tried which I have post in my question can u pls suggest any other solution or permanent working solution

Comment: Oh. sure let me see and get back to you in a while

Comment: I tried your code and it worked after a little modification. You were passing same corners in the method thats why it wasnt working. I have update my answer, and it contains both Objective C and Swift code. Please let me know for any help.